# how can I solve this error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android Studio... 
I followed another answer about error: package android.support.design.widget does not exist.

I applied this code
`implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.2'`
in app>build.gradle. but it does not work. how can i solve this problem?

This is my code

app > build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication2"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:29.0.2'`

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

And this is build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.`

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Please help me...

[image]

Comment: Did you try sync with gradle and clear and rebuild project?

Comment: yeah I did, but it still didn't work...

Comment: There is no version 29 of the design support library. They all switched over to androidx at version 28. You're apparently already using androidx for other things. Just update whatever example you're following to use androidx components.